# Class in loaded SWF cannot use base class in loading SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swfloader, swc

I have two SWF files which I shall call `container` `and slave`. The `slave` file contains a movieclip that extends from a class I shall call `base`. `base` extends `MovieClip` and is compiled into an SWC. `slave` includes this SWC as a runtime library, while `container` includes it as merged (and does reference it so it should be compiled into the `container` SWF).

The `container` loads the `slave` like so:

```
bgURLRequest = new URLRequest(slaveUrl);
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain( null ), SecurityDomain.currentDomain);          
bgLoader.load(bgURLRequest, context);
```

When this loading happens, I get the error that class `base` was not found. I suspect this has something to do with the presence of the `ApplicationDomain` in there. I'm not sure what it does exactly, since I didn't write this loading code myself (but I do know that it's there for a reason so it can't be simply removed).

How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution

```
new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain( ApplicationDomain.currentDomain ), SecurityDomain.currentDomain);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ApplicationDomain.currentDomain and track the available classes with the super getDefinitionNames available at: http://etcs.ru/pre/getDefinitionNamesSource/

At least you'll know whats available in the loaded swf.